# Php count number of how many changed = y where humen=yes

Tags: php, mysql

I tried something like this:

```
    $changed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE changed = 'y' AND human = '$_GET[human]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100", $link);
$num_rowsc = mysql_num_rows($changed);
```

So what i want is to select last 100 where human = yes and count where changed = y ..

so get last 100 humans and count how many of them have on changed yes

Comment: It ought to be `'{$_GET['human']}'`, and actually it ought to be `'$sql_human'` where `$sql_human` has been properly sanitized. What if I sent `http://...?human='%20OR%20admin=1%20--'` or something likewise unfunny? To count, you might investigate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SELECT...`.

Comment: i tried many of your solution and i get Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: See JoeT's answer (with my comment's correction). That ought to work. But get some good SQL manual, or you're setting yourself up for a fall.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with this query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT * FROM games 
    WHERE human = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[human])."'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
) tmp WHERE changed = 'y'
```

Comment: well it's not what he asked for: how many human = yes are in last 100 rows

Comment: @JoeT, I think Lajos Veres got it right, could you elaborate?

Comment: The question asked how many of the last 100 are human.  So we need to find the last 100, then see how many are human.  This answer finds the last 100 that were human then sees how many were changed.  It's really not clear what the OP wants wrt the changed column.

Comment: Please fix your SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: tried this `$nr221 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT * FROM games 
    WHERE human = '$_GET[human]' /* better using parametrized queries here */
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
) WHERE changed = 'y'", $link);` still didnt worked :(

Comment: So what i want is select last 100 where human = yes and count where changed = y ..

Comment: Can you try the actual version?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ( SELECT * FROM games 
                        WHERE human= :human ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
                        ) WHERE changed = 'y' ");
$stmt->bindParam(':human', $_GET[human]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Please fix your SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: This is not what he asked for. You are checking *changed humans* in the last 100 rows. He wants humans in the last 100 (changed?) rows, as per @JoeT's answer.

Comment: So move "changed = 'y'" to the inner sub-query

Comment: @Iserni : The question changed from the time is answered it. Have updated my answer to meet the changes.

Comment: are you sure you dont need " before Select instead of ' and also at the end " is not needed?

Comment: got the error again i try to do a pdo database connection to see if it resolves anything

Comment: Saw that. And +1'ing for the PDO solution

Comment: ok now after connecting to database i get [HERE IS THE LINK](http://umovies.org/joc/stats.php?l=y&human=no) i get ARRAY answer :( what i changed is : `$stmt->execute();
$red = $stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: you don't need fetchAll() to get the result. It is just a single value so you can assign it to a variable as $count=$stmt->execute();

Answer (score 1):

1) try using this as your query:
`SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM games WHERE changed = 'y' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100) WHERE human = '$_GET[human]'`
2) use mysqli

Comment: `(SELECT human FROM games... LIMIT 100) AS changes WHERE human...` (else, `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`). And you only need the `human` column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as cnt from (
SELECT human FROM games WHERE human = '$_GET[human]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
) as changes WHERE changed = 'y'
```

Comment: i put null because with sql server its best practices. thanks for the comment. cheers